# Best way to insert 1million records using spring rest and data jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, cloud-foundry

When we are trying to insert 1million records by using spring batch inserts, we are end up with more than 1min time and customised pivotal cloud foundry sending back 502 bad gateway response to the client even actual data insertion happening in the background.

Could you please let me know the best way to handle bulk data inserts that could be processed in less time?

Comment: By writing optimal code? But you have not provided your code so

Answer (score 0):

I would say spring batch is the right approach.

Well, i would upload the file via API return a process id. Later on i can ask the state about the process, if done, or failed or whatever. This implementation details is up to. In this case it doesn't matter if you upload a file with 10 entries, 1.000.000 or 100.000.000 entries.

But while reading the file with a lot of entries i would suggest to process them in chunks. This is perfectly for keeping the data in memory small and persisting a lot of data (chunk size) in once. Of course you shouldn't load the file in once, if possible use stream, or read the file line by line.

When persisting the data, you persist the chunks in a batch. Use PreparedStatemant and its addBatch / executeBatch command, which is in my eyes the fastest way to do it in an application.

There are two good entries at baeldung you should read:

[Baeldung.com - Spring Batch - Tasklets vs Chunks](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-batch-tasklet-chunk) - Take a look at the chunks part.

[Baeldung.com - Batch Processing in JDBC](https://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-batch-processing) - Take a look for the PreparedStatement

Comment: Let me know if it worked, or if you need some more help.